# Convex polygon Containment inside Concave polygon with rotational angles

Tags: algorithm, polygon, computational-geometry, convex-hull, concave

I have a convex polygon (Polygon A ) and a concave polygon (Polygon B). I want to figure out whether the convex polygon given a rotational angle for the convex polygon , fits inside the concave polygon given the convex polygon can rotate 360 degrees inside the concave polygon .

Naive way of computing this .

Initialise the polygon A with the midpoint of Polygon B as origin .
For every rotational angle of convex polygon compute the following

Step 1:  Compute points correspond to convex polygon with rotational
angle . Put all the points of both rotated convex polygon and
concave polygon in one set 
Step 2:  Find the convex polygon using grahamscan (Convex Hull) with the new set of points. 
Step 3:  Now you have a big convex polygon which will contain both polygons .That means you have vertex of the newly created polygon. Let's call it Polygon C 
Step 4: Now check if polygon C and Polygon B are same
with same set of vertex points if yes that means Polygon B contains
Polygon A

One potential optimisation might be to utilise the angle of rotational symmetry but I am not sure if we can use this .  Since we are dealing with convex polygons we are bound to find the first symmetry at (360/n) degree . Where n is the number of vertices .

[Symmetry of rotation for a square example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv802.png)

Can we map angle of rotation say 1 degree rotation correspond to 91 degree rotation in case of the above example and be done with the process up to the rotational angle of symmetry ?

Any other efficient way of solving this problem without iterating through all the angles of rotation . Any pointers would be appreciated .

Comment: There are infinitely many angles of rotation.

Comment: I am afraid that your procedure makes no sense and is not even well defined. "Step 1": how ? "Step 4": this property does not hold.

Comment: Look into "polygon in polygon" algorithms. Rotate the inner polygon by the angle, then check if the inner polygon is inside the outer polygon.